# Sample properties of a Gaussian process with a Matérn covariance function

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, covariance

I read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat%C3%A9rn_covariance_function) that a Gaussian process with a Matérn covariance function is $\lfloor\nu\rfloor$ times mean-square differentiable, where $\nu$ is the smoothness parameter of the Matérn covariance function. What can I say about the sample differentiability or continuity (or differentiability or continuity with probability one) of these processes? I guess there are some simple results but I cannot seem to find them...

**Edit:** I found [this Math Overflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/288250) and [these lecture slides](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/teaching/4f13/1920/covariance%20functions.pdf), which state that the sample functions from a Gaussian process with a Matérn covariance function are $\lfloor\nu\rfloor - 1$ times differentiable. Unfortunately, the links come without any derivations. Any ideas where to find those?